# c# Как назначить объекту его тип глобально?

Tags: c#, объекты

Есть 4 объекта

```
public object ObjectGet = { get; set; }
public Object1TType Object1 = new Object1TType();
public Object2TType Object2 = new Object2TType();
public object Object3Set = new();
...
if ... => ObjectGet = new Object1TType(...)
else => ObjectGet = new Object2TType(...)
```

Я знаю что можно завести **Object3Set** в самом коде:

```
if (ObjectGet is Object1TType)
{
    Object3Set = ObjectGet as Object1TType;
}
else if (ObjectGet is Object2TType)
{
    Object3Set = ObjectGet as Object2TType;
}
```

А как изменить тип объекта **object Object3Set** на **Object1TType** или **Object2TType** в зависимости от типа объекта глобально, чтобы можно было обращаться к **Object3Set.Field** (при условии того, что я знаю что в данном месте это 100% например **Object1TType**) без надобности заведения **Object3Set** локально?

Пример рабочего кода:
***1.cs***

```
namespace ObjectType
{
    public class Object1TType : ICloneable
    {
        public ulong Field { get; set; }
        public Object1TType()
        {
        }

        public Object1TType( ulong Field)
        {
            this.Field = Field;
        }
        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Object1TType(Field);
        }
    }

    public class Object2TType : ICloneable
    {
        public ulong Field { get; set; }
        public Object2TType()
        {
        }

        public Object2TType(ulong Field)
        {
            this.Field = Field;
        }
        public object Clone()
        {
            return new Object2TType(Field);
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public static object ObjectGet = new Object1TType();

        public static void Do()
        {
            ulong test = 123;
                ObjectGet = new Object2TType(test);
        }
    }
}
```

***2.cs***

```
namespace Code
{
    public class Main
    {
        public object ObjectGet = ObjectType.Class1.ObjectGet;
        public object Object3Set = new();

        public void Do()
        {
            ObjectType.Class1.Do();
            if (ObjectGet is ObjectType.Object1TType)
            {
                Object3Set = ObjectGet as ObjectType.Object1TType;
            }
            else if (ObjectGet is ObjectType.Object2TType)
            {
                Object3Set = ObjectGet as ObjectType.Object2TType;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Object3Set.Field);
        }
    }
}
```

тут я не могу обращаться к **ObjectGet.Field** и к **Object3Set.Field**, для этого я думаю нужно что-то сделать с **Object3Set** и работать с ним

Comment: Глобально как к статической переменной? Приведите реальную структуру классов и пример где и зачем вам это нужно.

Comment: @User, обновил описание

Comment: Нужно больше информации богу StackOverFlow)) Я могу просто посоветовать использовать ключевое слово dynamic. Но это крайний случай, Что это за метод Do? Что за поле Field? Методы и поля есть в обоих классах? Если да - то приведите их, если у этих классов нужные вам методы и поля разные, то только ключевое слово dynamic. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Comment: Приведите **реальный** пример

Comment: @User обновил, код по значимости равен реальному

Comment: Примечание: интерфейс `ICloneable` не используется ни в одном месте в стандартной библиотеке .NET. Имеется в виду, что хоть его и реализуют некоторые классы, но его не принимает ни один метод. Он давно признан неудачным решением и не рекомендуется к использованию. Если нужен метод клонирования, то создайте его без всяких интерфейсов, и пусть он возвращает конкретный тип, а не object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface IObjectTType
{
    UInt64 Field { get; set; }
}
public class Object1TType : ICloneable, IObjectTType
{
    public UInt64 Field { get; set; }
}
public class Object2TType : ICloneable, IObjectTType
{
    public ulong Field { get; set; }
}
public class Class1
{
    public static IObjectTType ObjectGet = new Object1TType();
}
public class Main
{
    public IObjectTType ObjectGet = ObjectType.Class1.ObjectGet;
    public object Object3Set = new();

    public void Do()
    {
          
        ObjectType.Class1.Do();
        Console.WriteLine(ObjectGet.Field);
    }
}
```

Можно использовать интерфейсы/абстрактные классы/наследования классов для реализации общего функционала ваших объектов.

`Object3Set` - никак не задействована, зачем она...

p.s. пространство имён `ObjectType` совпадает с название класса `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ObjectType` избегайте таких совпадений дабы избежать путаницы с IDE.

Comment: Вот да, непонятно зачем нужны лишние преобразования, если оба класса могут просто реализовывать нужный интерфейс и можно прямо к нему обращаться, без приведения классов :)

Comment: Это тестовый код для ознакомления с возможностями языка, а кто не наступал на все эти очевидные грабли?) Вот человек и пробует свою 1-ю сотню грабл

Comment: я забыл дописать преобразования с Object3Set, добавил